# How can I git push to a destination that does not exist yet

Tags: git

I am trying to create a new branch on the git server using a hash, but without creating the branch locally too:

```
$ git push origin HEAD^:new-branch
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: new-branch
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github:company/repo.git'
```

This works when you force push over an existing branch.  I have tried making the destination `refs/new-branch` and it says:

```
$ git push origin HEAD^:refs/new-branch
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to create funny ref 'refs/new-branch' remotely
To github.com:company/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected]       HEAD^ -> refs/new-branch (funny refname)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:company/repo.git'
```

What is the format for a destination that doesn't exist yet?

I am going to work around it like this

```
$ git branch new-branch
$ git push origin new-branch
$ git push origin HEAD^:new-branch -f
$ git branch -D new-branch
```

or like this

```
$ git branch new-branch HEAD^
$ git push origin new-branch
$ git branch -D new-branch
```

but is would be to know how to create a new branch on the server without ever creating it locally

Comment: Why do you want to even do this?  I think GitHub web's interface allows for creating a true remote branch directly on GitHub.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `--set-upstream` flag. Eg: `git push --set-upstream origin [your-branch-name]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branches are `refs/heads/...`, not simply `refs/...` so you should push to `refs/heads/new-branch` to create a new branch on the remote repository.

```
git push origin HEAD^:refs/heads/new-branch
```